# Select sepcific strings in different columns and print it AWK

Tags: search, awk, find

I have syntax :

```
awk -F'\t' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if($i~/ensembl_gene_id*/) {h=$i}} ;for(a=1;a<=NF;a++) {if($a~/ensembl_gn*/) {z=$a}} print $1,$2,$3,z,h}'
```

This is syntax for search more strings in multiple unspecific fields separated by "\t" and print them. But my skills are not so good and I would like to rewrite it with only one loop (Now I have got two loops for "i" and "a"). Could you help me to get easier way with awk? (Code is working).

I think something like this :

```
awk -F'\t' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if($i~/ensembl_gene_id* | esnembl_gn*/) {h=$i}}  {print $1,$2,$3,h}'
```

But it prints only first match.

INPUT:

```
1 2 les ensembl_gene_id=aaa aha ensembl_gn=BRAF 
2 3 pes ccds ensembl_gene_id=kkk ahl klkl ensembl_gn=OTC 
2 2 ves ccds=1 ccds=2 ensembl_gene_id=cac ensembl_gn=BRCA
```

OUTPUT:

```
1 2 les ensembl_gene_id=aaa ensembl_gn=BRAF
2 3 pes ensembl_gene_id=kkk ensembl_gn=OTC
2 2 ves ensembl_gene_id=cac
```

Thank you

Comment: How about some sample data with the expected output?

Comment: Is `OUTPUT` the output you **want** or the output you currently get that you don't want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT:*** After seeing OP's samples adding following solution.(change `awk` to `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}` in case your Input_file is TAB delimited and your output should be in TAB delimited too.

```
awk '
match($0,/ensembl_gene_id[^ ]*/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
}
match($0,/ensembl_gn[^ ]*/){
  val1=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
}
{
  print $1,$2,$3,val,val1
  val=val1=""
}
'  Input_file
```

---

---

As far as I understood from your question(you want to run single `for` loop and check 2 conditions. if yes then we need not to use 2 loops rather we can use single loop with 2 conditions in it), could you please try following.

```
awk -F'\t' '{h=z="";for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/ensembl_gene_id*/){h=$i};if($i~/ensembl_gn*/){z=$i}};print $1,$2,$3,z,h}'  Input_file
```

OR(a non-one liner form of solution):

```
awk '
{
  h=z=""
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i~/ensembl_gene_id*/){
      h=$i
    }
    if($i~/ensembl_gn*/){
      z=$i
    }
  }
  print $1,$2,$3,z,h
}
'  Input_file
```

Issue with OP's attempt: It will always print 1 value only since in case other character's finding it will overwrite its previous value.

Comment: Right this is what I want... I tried it similar way, but I forgot define h=z=" " and I used if and another condition else if. Thank you

Comment: @Vonton, yes nullifying them will save us from printing them when they are NOT found in a line. Also for your attempt you are using only 1 variable for 2 condititons which will cause overwriting the variable's value in case both strings are found in a single line, will add explanation to my solution in sometime too.

Comment: @Vonton, after seeing your samples I have added EDIT solution, please check once. We need not to use for loop for this, please do let me know ?

Comment: It is printing all fields.. But "match" is really great function, I did know about it.

Comment: @Vonton, Thanks. But it is NOT printing all fields, kindly check it once more. Values like `ccds` or `ccds=1 ccds=2` are NOT there in output, kindly confirm once.

Comment: Right, I tried it without FS and OFS specification. Now It is working. Great job and thanks, that you showed me "match" function in awk

Comment: @Vonton, cool, glad that it helped you, cheers and happy learning.

Answer (score 1):

Are just trying to print the ensembl_gene_id and ensembl_gn fields? That'd be:

```
$ awk '{
    delete f
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        split($i,t,/=/)
        f[t[1]] = $i
    }
    print $1, $2, $3, f["ensembl_gene_id"], f["ensembl_gn"]
}' file
1 2 les ensembl_gene_id=aaa ensembl_gn=BRAF
2 3 pes ensembl_gene_id=kkk ensembl_gn=OTC
2 2 ves ensembl_gene_id=cac ensembl_gn=BRCA
```